# Как отключить авто скролл вверх после выполнения json success?

Tags: javascript, json

Как отключить авто скролл вверх после выполнения json success ? 
- Проблема в href="#" - вот что вызывает скролл вверх при нажатии. Нужно по другому делать кнопку.

```js
<a href="#" onclick="skrit('1')"  > Запустить </a>


    function skrit(d1){
       
        var data='d1='+d1;
     
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '1.php', 
                type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
                data: data,  
        
        success: function(json) {
         if (json['error']) {
        // -----
         } else if (json['success']) {
          
        // после success нужно отключить авто скролл вверх. 

         }
       }  
            });
    }



//----------------- 1.php
<?
require_once('../connect/connect.php');

if(isset($_POST["d1"])) {


  mysql_query("DELETE FROM tab WHERE id='"$_POST["d1"]."' ");
  
 
 $json['success'] = true;
}
else{
 $json['error'] = '- Ошибка при удалении.';
} 
  

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Не вижу в коде ничего, что могло бы вызывать "авто скролл вверх"

Comment: @MedvedevDev , но он есть , после выполнения POST запроса в 1.php.

Comment: @МаксимС а в вопросе он где ?)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, в названии.

Comment: @МаксимС код... нужен код...

Comment: @МаксимС, если вы привели весь код и в нем не наблюдается ничего что могло бы вызвать скролл, то возможно это просто магия, вызывайте фиксиков.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, код есть.

Comment: php тут точно ни при чем.

Comment: Проблема в href="#"  - вот что вызывает скролл вверх при нажатии.

Comment: @МаксимС, если это так, то должно отрабатывать не только при саксесс .... но если ваше предположение верно, то добавил ответ, должно помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function skrit( d1 ) {
  var data = 'd1='+d1;
  
  $.ajax({ 
    url: '1.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,  
    success: function(json) {
      if (json['error']) {
        // -----
      } else if (json['success']) {
        // после success нужно отключить авто скролл вверх. 
      }
    }  
  });
}
```

```html
<!--
-  Перед вызовом функции требуется вызвать event.preventDefault(),
-  что бы отменить стандартное поведение якорной ссылки
-->
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();skrit(1);"> Запустить </a>
```

Comment: почему этот код должен помочь?

Comment: @Grundy, теория автора заключается в том, что скролл происходит из-за того, что это якорная ссылка, соответственно `event.preventDefault()` должно отменить скролл ... Честно говоря, я совсем не уверен, что это должно помочь и вообще будет работать xDD

Comment: Перенеси это объяснение в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в href="#" , заменил кнопку на input  type="button".